# What are the right parameters for a rspec put request on my stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a controller spec and I get following failed expectation:

```
 Failure/Error: put :update, :id => login_user.id, :user => valid_attributes
   #<User:0xbd030bc> received :update_attributes with unexpected arguments
     expected: ({:name=>"changed name", :email=>"changed@mail.com", :password=>"secret", :password_confirmation=>"secret"})
          got: ({"name"=>"Test user", "email"=>"user@test.com", "password"=>"secret", "password_confirmation"=>"secret"})
```

And for me it looks like I am passing in `"name" => "Test User"` and I am expecting `:name => "test user"`

my spec looks like this:

```
    describe 'with valid parameters' do
      it 'updates the user' do
       login_user = User.create!(valid_attributes)
       controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(login_user)
       User.any_instance.
          should_receive(:update_attributes).
          with(valid_attributes.merge(:email => "changed@mail.com",:name=>"changed name"))
       put :update, :id => login_user.id, :user => valid_attributes
      end 
end
```

and I have something like this for my valid attributes:

```
    def valid_attributes
  {
    :name => "Test user",
    :email=> "user@test.com",
    :password => "secret",
    :password_confirmation => "secret"

  }
end
```

so what is wrong with my parameters any suggestions?

I am using Rails 3.0.5 with rspec 2.6.0...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The failure message is telling you exactly what's going on: any instance of `User` is expecting `update_attributes` with a hash including `:email => "changed@mail.com"`, but it's getting `:email => "user@test.com"` because that's what's in `valid_attributes`. Similarly, it's expecting `:name => "changed_name"`, but gets `:name => "Test user"` because that's what's in `valid_attributes`.

You can simplify this example and avoid this confusion. There is no need to use `valid_attributes` here because `should_receive` intercepts the `update_attributes` call anyhow. I usually do this like so:

```
controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(mock_model(User)) # no need for a real user here
User.any_instance.
  should_receive(:update_attributes).
  with({"these" => "params"})
put :update, :id => login_user.id, :user => {"these" => "params"}
```

This way the expected and actual values are right in the example and it makes clear that it doesn't really matter what they are: whatever hash is passed in as `:user` is passed directly to `update_attributes`.

Make sense?

Comment: yes makes sense and works... I was just expecting if I pass in my valid_attributes in my put qequest that they were the same as when I pass them into the with method, that's all. But your way works ... thanks